# Access Report - unbound Textbox value not printed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have unbound Textbox on my Report. Textbox show value from a field in another form. Value is shown in Report view, but not in PrintPreview, and It doesn't get printed too. What must I do to see this Textbox value allways, and print It ?

Here is a simple code for Textbox (in Report load_Event):

```
Me.txtReport.Value = Forms![AnotherForm]![TxtForm].Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved It. I had to remove all code from Report Load and just put a reference to fields from other form, in Textbox recordsource property, like this:

```
=[Forms]![SomeForm]![SomeControlOnThatForm]
```

This way you can have Textbox value in Report view or Print view - and It gets printed. I hope this will save time to somebody in future, having same problems.